# Why do I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

Here is my for loop, is my for loop wrong? I have not been doing loops for a very long time so I am still a beginner and I would really appreciate if someone could take a look at my problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    if (tab != null) {
        tab.setCustomView(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
    }else{
        System.out.println("ERROR---TAB IS NULL---ERROR");
    }

}
```

and here is my `Count` Method and `Char`

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    // return tabTitles[position];

    // getDrawable(int i) is deprecated, use getDrawable(int i, Theme theme) for min SDK >=21
    // or ContextCompat.getDrawable(Context context, int id) if you want support for older versions.
    // Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconIds[position], context.getTheme());
    // Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);

    Drawable image = ContextCompat.getDrawable(MainActivity.this, imageResId[position]);
    image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
    SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
    sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return sb;
}
```

Comment: What programming language is this in?

Comment: Did you log `tabLayout.getTabCount()` to check number of tab?

Comment: Why are you returning 4 for 3 pages. Java has a 0 index?

Comment: _there are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors_. What line does this occur on? When you get an error the two things you do are: 1. Work out what line it's on; 2 Look up the error online